# JAX RS: OpenApi3 generation and validation via maven

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, openapi

Here is how I develop Jax Rs/REST services:

1. Define REST API module: Create rest interfaces with Jax Rs annotations on it. Server component depends on this module. It is also provided to clients, if they want to use it.
2. Generate rest documentation. `Enunciate` is used for it. The documentation is included into the war file and is available to the client via `/docs` url.
3. Add GUI to send rest requests at runtime to the server. Via `Swagger`. `swagger.json` is generated also via `swagger` module of `Enunciate`.
4. Now lots of clients ask you to provide OpenApi 3 specification of your rest services. To help them to generate clients and mock services. Ok, `Enunciate` also via additional dependency allows to do it, and now I have also `openapi.yml` file, which is put into web resources ans is accessible via url to the clients.
5. Server-side logic implements the rest interfaces.
6. Rest clients use the interfaces and generate proxies.

**My question is**: how to validate this `openapi.yml` file during maven build process. The library which generates it might not do that. If it is not valid, I want to see, what is wrong in the file. I need something like `OpenAPI4J`, its validation modules, but check the yml file itself.

I might create a custom maven plugin, but hope there is already an existing solution. For now I found a lot of examples with OpenApi but they are about how to generate stubs or client code from the spec file. I could not find anything about validation.

In case the way how I use openapi.yml is wrong and I miss something, please let me know.